# found java.util.Date but required java.sql.Date?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to create a function to check if a string is a date. However, the following function got the error.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import java.sql._
import scala.util.{Success, Try}

    def validateDate(date: String): Boolean = {
      val df = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd")
      val test = Try[Date](df.parse(date))
      test match  {
        case Success(_) => true
        case _ => false
      }
    }
```

Error:

```
[error] C:\Users\user1\IdeaProjects\sqlServer\src\main\scala\main.scala:14: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : java.util.Date
[error]  required: java.sql.Date
[error]       val test = Try[Date](df.parse(date))
[error]                                    ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed May 17, 2017 1:19:33 PM
```

Is there a simpler way to validate if a string is a date without create a function?

The function is used to validate the command line argument.

```
if (args.length != 2 || validateDate(args(0))) { .... }
```

Comment: you imported `java.sql._` - so `test` has the type `Try[java.sql.date]` - try replacing that import with `import java.util.Date`

Comment: I will need Java.sql. so I guess I will need the full quoted type name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. `Try[Date](df.parse(date))` You are not interested in type here because you ignore it. So simply omit type parameter. `Try(df.parse(date))`.
2. Your function could be shorter. `Try(df.parse(date)).isSuccess` instead pattern matching.
3. If your environment contains java 8 then use `java.time` package always.

   ```
   import scala.util.Try
   import java.time.LocalDate
   import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

   // Move creation of formatter out of function to reduce short lived objects allocation.
   val df = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy MM dd")

   def datebleStr(s: String): Boolean = Try(LocalDate.parse(s,df)).isSuccess
   ```

Answer (score 0):

use this:   import java.util.Date

Comment: I changed the statement to `val test = Try[java.util.Date](df.parse(date))`. Because I will need java.sql._